# How to delete peewee model object field

Tags: python, orm, peewee

I use peewee orm in python.
I get user data

```
user = User.select().where(User.user_id==1).get()
```

user object has password field. I don't want send user password data from api.
I'm trying `del user.password` but it throws error that `AttributeError: __delete__`. Is there easy way to delete peewee object fields. I don't want to write select condition like that:

```
User.select(User.user_id, User.email, User.full_name) ....
```

Comment: Sorry for necroing this thread - but if someone bumps here, you can use `model_to_dict` function and operate as on regular dict, if you don't need specifically the object.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no you cannot delete the instance attributes. You could always just set it to `None` though.